# Восстановление пути в графе

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, любой-язык, графы

Имеется поиск в ширину в неявном графе. Узлов очень много, потому, строя новый слой графа,  удаляем, допустим, узлы предыдущего (ибо памяти не хватает) в какой-то момент мы достигаем цели, каким образом восстановить путь до неё?
Может, зная точную глубину и положение в слое можно как-то оптимальнее построить вторым проходом путь? Или в процессе построения сохранять какие-то минимальные ориентиры?

Comment: Берем поиск в ширину и смотрим, как он работает. И видим, что он требует как-то помечать уже пройденные узлы, чтоб не попадать в них повторно. Как вы обеспечиваете этот момент при удалении узлов? Что вообще означает это ваше "удаление"? Если граф уже есть и в памяти - то что вы таким образом экономите?

Comment: Возможно вам подойдет какое-нибудь иерархическое разбиение/представление графа.

Comment: @Harry, Его нет в памяти, потому я его и назвал неявным, мы его строим на лету. Повторно мы в них не попадём, т.к. это исключает логика построения, т.е пока обходим последний слой в очереди строится следующий. Учитывая специфику это больше напоминает дерево, чем граф

Comment: @Isaev если это дерево. То лучше строить его снизу вверх. И использовать по сути алгоритм общего предка.

Comment: @pavel, снизу вверх не получится, т.к. построение идёт от заданного начального состояния и до чего оно доветвится книзу не предсказуемо